NEXTJS: Change url From server action and send data to client
I have a client component with form. Validation of form happens inside server action and if there are errors server action sends them to client. But if form was successfullly submitted I need to add ?showModal=true to url. When I use redirect(/currentPath?showModal=true) Next throws error because client expects state to update validation fields.
client component 
// ...
const [state, action] = useFormState(bookingData, { message: '' });
// ...


// server action 

if (Object.keys(errors).length) {
    return {
      errors,
      message: 'Validation Error',
    };
  }
redirect('/book-appointment?showDialog=y');

Is it possible to change url from server action and at the same time give client message to clear validation fields?



// server action
if (Object.keys(errors).length) {
  return {
    errors,
    message: 'Validation Error',
  };
}





const result = await response.json();

  if (result.errors) {
    // Update state with validation errors
    action.setErrors(result.errors);
    action.setMessage(result.message);
  } else {
    // Clear validation errors
    action.setErrors({});
    action.setMessage(result.message);

    // Update the URL and show the modal
    router.push('/book-appointment?showDialog=y', undefined, { shallow: true });
  }
};




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
